# Laravel 5.3 Error : Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

The code below has an error. I am using Laravel 5.3 and php 7.0.

I google it but still not clear, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**ActivationService.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;


use Illuminate\Mail\Mailer;
use Illuminate\Mail\Message;

class ActivationService
{

    protected $mailer;

    protected $activationRepo;

    protected $resendAfter = 24;

    public function __construct(Mailer $mailer, ActivationRepository $activationRepo)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->activationRepo = $activationRepo;
    }

    public function sendActivationMail($user)
    {

        if ($user->activated || !$this->shouldSend($user)) {
            return;
        }

        $token = $this->activationRepo->createActivation($user);

        $link = route('user.activate', $token);
        $message = sprintf('Activate account <a href="%s">%s</a>', $link, $link);

        $this->mailer->raw($message, function (Message $m) use ($user) {
            $m->to($user->email)->subject('Activation mail');
        });


    }

    public function activateUser($token)
    {
        $activation = $this->activationRepo->getActivationByToken($token);

        if ($activation === null) {
            return null;
        }

        $user = User::find($activation->user_id);
        //Below is line 53.
        $user->activated = true;

        $user->save();

        $this->activationRepo->deleteActivation($token);

        return $user;

    }

    private function shouldSend($user)
    {
        $activation = $this->activationRepo->getActivation($user);
        return $activation === null || strtotime($activation->created_at) + 60 * 60 * $this->resendAfter < time();
    }

}
```

**Error message**

> ErrorException in ActivationService.php line 53: Creating default object from empty value

Line 53 of the code above is like this:

```
$user->activated = true;
```

How could I settle the issue?

Comment: `$user = User::find($activation->user_id);` returns `false` or `null`, probably. Have you tried dumping `$activation->user_id`? Why don't you use `Auth::user()->id` instead?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely because `$user = User::find($activation->user_id);` returns **null** or **false**.

When you end up in these kinds of situations always try dumping the variable where the problem is occurring, in this case `dd($activation->user_id)`

I would suggest using `Auth::user()->id` instead.